# Why generic arguments type not assignable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why the ts code below wrong?

```
type Bar<T> = { value: T }

function bar(options: { callback: <T>(data: Bar<T>) => void }) {}

bar({
    callback(data: Bar<string>) {}
})
```

[image]

Comment: You've got the generic incorrectly scoped for that. The caller decides a generic type argument, not the implementer. You can't *implement* `callback` to accept `Bar<string>`, it must be any `T` the caller of `callback` wants.  You should put `T` on `bar` and not `callback`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQjMGN). See the answers to the other questions for more information.

Comment: (see prev comment) If it turns out that doesn't suffice and you want this question reopened, please make sure to [edit] so that it clearly distinguishes itself from those questions, and additionally 
[please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)